# Hibernate query returning error

Tags: hibernate

I have the following hibernate query -

```
    events = (List<Event>)session.createQuery(
            "Event where eventName like " 
            + "\"" + event.getEventName() 
            + "\"" +
            " and startingDate >=   "
            + "\"" + 
            event.getStartingDate() 
            + "\" " +
            " and endingDate <=  " 
            + "\"" + 
            event.getEndingDate()
            + "\" "
            ).list();
```

But it returns the error -

org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '"' [Event where eventName like "test" and startingDate >=   "2011-01-19"  and endingDate <=  "2011-01-31" ]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)

Seems to be saying it does'nt like a " somewhere ?

It worked fine until I added the date fields to the where clause.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you should use the single quote char to delimit strings. Like this: 'string'. Second, don't build queries by concatenating strings. Use parameter markers, like this:

```
Event where eventName like ? and startingDate >= ? and endingDate <= ?
Event where eventName like :name and startingDate >= :startDate and endingDate <= :endDate
```

Then, call the `setParameter()` method from the `Query` object to set the parameters. You can use positional parameters (like, "? in position 0 is 'name'") or named parameters (":name is 'name'"). See the section "Bind parameters" from the Hibernate documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing